# Extjs PropertyGrid with multiple Sources

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Is it possible to have an extjs (classic) propertygrid with multiple columns for multiple data sources? We want a component where we can manage the pricelists/product matrix. Of course, we could do it with a table but this looks strange since you might only have two rows then and is far off from how the end result would look like. We are right now on extjs 6.x with the classic toolkit. How would you implement such a component based on the grid component since every column is expected to have one datatype but for a propertygrid every row column can be different in type?

Comment: I would use a normal grid for this task since it is much more versatile. When facing similar problems, I programmatically create and set the store data and the columns (first one static and then one for each source). Then I use the grid reconfigure() method.

Comment: Choose Component and render you data from XTemplate mb?
You have your template, custom logic and same tricks for render your data and you wanna control your data, functions and more.
But this option have some problems: more code for impl some data. view rendering, logic for choose parameters and more....
If you wanna edit - create listener for change at filed and display modal(bad option) or transfer to other form, where u can edit field or ur customer.

Answer (score 1):

I created an [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34nk) of the grid you need. I overridу some `celleditor` methods and the `headercontainer`(used in propertygrid) constructor (this should not affect the other components), and I also defined a new component, the columns (additionalColumns) of which can be supplement in the same way as in the grid.
With help `verticalCellTypes` you can specify the same data types for the column or row

Comment: guess you misunderstood me. We want to edit multiple records and every column is a new record.

Name | Record1 | Record2 | Record3
Description | Test | test2 | Test3
Required | true | false | true
maxValue | 10 | 2000 | 0

This would be the desired design. Would be good if we could bind a record property as cell header. Can your code be adjusted to meet this requirements?

Comment: `Name | Record1 | Record2 | Record3 [br]
Description | Test | test2 | Test3[br]
Required | true | false | true[br]
maxValue | 10 | 2000 | 0`

Comment: You mean headercontainer must be vertical?

Comment: I would say thats how a property grid is, right? On the left/ right you have the properties and every column represents one record. The records use normal models.